# EF Core Create a field that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core - Code First to load data from a SQLite file.
The problem is I updated the schema of the new SQLite DB files and added fields in a table. It works fine for the newly generated DB. but,  when I try to open an old file, I got an exception. I don't really understand EF. I need help cause I have 2 questions :

- Is it possible to avoid getting the exception if the field doesn't exist ? (If so, an example could be very nice)
- If not, is it possible to auto update a SQLite file if the fields are missing ?

Thank you in advance.

**Exception I got :**

As you can see, the field COMMENT doesn't exist in table GAP.

```
SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: g.COMMENT'.
    à Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, Sqlite3Handle db)
    à Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    à Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    à System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
    à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
    à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
    à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
    à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
    à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, TState state)
    à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
    à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
    à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
    à     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
    à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
    à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    à Dodo.GapTable.LoadData() dans d:\SYNC\DLSFile\Dodo\Table\GapTable.cs:ligne 35
```

Comment: When you have an error and you ask a question about that error you need to include that error. An error that occurs at runtime this case its called an `Exception` (*this is how errors manifest themselves in .net*). Include the `Message`, the `Type`, the `StackTrace`, and repeat this recursively across `InnerException`s all the way down. Use the  [edit] link on your question to include that detail, do not include it as a comment. Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: EF does not "create" fields. It queries the database that matches its model. Either you have a property called "Comment" in the type and failed to create/apply a migration upon targeting an old database or the mapping tells EF to look for the Column "Comment". Note also that the exception refers to the missing column (SqlException), in which case EF will usually throw an EntityCommandExecutionException.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into a migration issue.

Your 'new' database that is working is probably using the most up-to-date migration.

When trying access an 'old' database file, you likely have not applied the migration to that file yet, and since your models have changed, they no longer match the schema of the database and will cause an error.

To complete a migration for your old databases, make sure the old database is targeted properly by your connection string in your `DbContext` class, and then run the command `update-database` (from the VS powershell) or `dotnet ef database update --project {your-project-path}` (from the command line)

Microsoft Docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/

Comment: Is it possible to apply migration directly in a c# program ? In my case, SQLite files are downloaded from a linux server and opened localy with a c# client i've made. I want the c# program to upgrade db before opening it.

Comment: Yes, migrations can be applied at run time. The link I provided has that information if you read until the end.